# Not able to use proxy for scraping using Selenium and python in Ubuntu server

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have two servers installed with ubuntu 20.04. I was trying to use proxy while scraping. In one of the server it is working fine but, in the other I am getting "ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED" error. I am using same selenium setting in both the servers and I have tried various setting mentioned in stack overflow but nothing is working in one server.

Comment: Can you write your traceback error here?

Comment: WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)

Comment: did you try to use proxies for sending requests?

Comment: driver.get('https://www.google.com'), driver is chromedriver. I have tried with request module also requests.get("https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check", proxies=proxy, headers={'User-Agent': header}) but got the error HTTPSConnectionPool(host='whatismyipaddress.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /proxy-check (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Comment: when I see errors like this I rotate my IP address and after this, my problem is solved and I suggest you use https://api.ipify.org to verify your IP address. it's more reliable

Comment: I have tested my IP address on my other server, it is working fine there. So it is not the problem with the IP. I have tested with 10 different proxies but not working.